# Design Model and Hints For Multithreaded Win Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, threadpool, task

I am trying to design a multithreaded windows application mostly serves for our clients to send emails fastly to their customers(there can be millions as there is a big telecommunication company), and I need design hints.(I am sorry that Q is long)

I fairly read articles about the multithreaded applications. I also read about SmartThread Pool, .NET ThreadPool, Task Parallel Library and other SO questions. But I could not come with a correct design. My logic is like that :

Within start of the program(Email engine), a timer starts and check if there any email campaigns in database(Campaigns table) that has Status 1(new campaign).

If there are, Campaign Subscribers should be queried from DB and should be written to another table(SqlBulkCopy) called SubscriberReports table and update the Campaign's Status to 2 in Campaigns table.

Timer also listens Campaigns with Status 2 to call another method to customize the campaign for each Subscriber, creates a Struct that has customized properties of the Subscriber.

Thirdly a SendEmail method is invoked to send the email via SMTP. What I tried so far is below(I know that ThreadPool is wrong here, and I have bunch of other mistakes). Can you pls suggest and help me how to design such an application. Highly appreciate any help. Thanks alot for your time.

```
private void ProcessTimer(object Source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Campaigns campaign = new Campaigns();
    IEnumerable<Campaigns> campaignsListStatusOne = // Get Campaign Properties to a List
    IEnumerable<Campaigns> campaignsListStatusTwo = // Get Campaign Properties to a List            

    foreach (Campaigns _campaign in campaignsListStatusOne)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CheckNewCampaign), _campaign.CampaignID);
    }

    foreach (Campaigns _campaign in campaignsListStatusTwo)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CustomizeMail), _campaign.CampaignID);
    }
}

private void CheckNewCampaign(object state)
{
    int campaignID = (int)state;
    DataTable dtCampaignSubscribers = // get subscribers based on Campaign ID
    campaign.UpdateStatus(campaignID, 2);
}

private void CustomizeMail(object state)
{
    int campaignID = (int)state;
    CampaignCustomazition campaignCustomizer;
    IEnumerable<SubscriberReports> reportList = // get subscribers to be sent from Reports table

    foreach (SubscriberReports report in reportList)
    {   // 3 database related methods are here
        campaignCustomizer = new CampaignCustomazition(report.CampaignID, report.SubscriberID);

        campaignCustomizer.CustomizeSource(report.CampaignID, report.SubscriberID, out campaignCustomizer.source, out campaignCustomizer.format);
        campaignCustomizer.CustomizeCampaignDetails(report.CampaignID, report.SubscriberID, out campaignCustomizer.subject, out campaignCustomizer.fromName, out campaignCustomizer.fromEmail, out campaignCustomizer.replyEmail);
        campaignCustomizer.CustomizeSubscriberDetails(report.SubscriberID, out campaignCustomizer.email, out campaignCustomizer.fullName);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendMail), campaignCustomizer);
    }
} 

private void SendMail(object state)
{
    CampaignCustomazition campaignCustomizer = new CampaignCustomazition();
    campaignCustomizer = (CampaignCustomazition)state;
    //send email based on info at campaignCustomizer via SMTP and update DB record if it is success.
 }
```

Comment: Try to write the application single threaded first, then see if the performance is good enough. If it is not, think about how to improve your code like writing the email to a drop-directory instead of connecting to a smtp server. Rewriting your access to the database, getting batches instead of single records. And handling your transactions.

Answer (score 3):

There is little to be gained here by using threading.  What threads buy you is more cpu cycles.  Assuming you have a machine with multiple cores, pretty standard these days.  But that's not what you need to get the job done quicker.  You need more dbase and email servers.  Surely you only have one of each.  Your program will burn *very* little core, it is constantly waiting for the dbase query and the email server to complete their job.

The only way to get ahead is to overlap the delays of each.  One thread could constantly be waiting for the dbase engine, the other could be constantly waiting for the email server.  Which is better than one thread waiting for both.

That's not likely to buy you much either though, there's a big mismatch between the two.  The dbase engine can give you thousands of email addresses in a second, the email server can only a few hundred emails in a second.  Everything is throttled by how fast the email server works.

Given the low odds of getting ahead, I'd recommend you don't try to get yourself into trouble with threading at all.  It has a knack for producing very hard to diagnose failure if you don't lock properly.  The amount of time you can spend on troubleshooting this can greatly exceed the operational gains from moving a wee bit faster.

If you are contemplating threading to avoid freezing a user interface then that's a reasonable use for threading.  Use BackgroundWorker.  The MSDN Library has excellent help for it.

Comment: Well, if the email server will permit more than one connection from the OP, a multiThreaded client will perform much, much faster than a 'wait ages over a high-latency network just for a TCP three-way/four-way connect/disconnect protocol' single-threaded client.  Threads buy you more than just CPU cycles - they assist in applying what CPU cycles you have in an effective manner.  In the case of a high-speed but high-latency network where multiple connections are permitted, a multi-thread email client would be hugely faster on a single-core box.

Comment: @Hans, thank you for the answer. But what if there are multiple campaigns to be sent at the same time. They have to be delivered at the time they arrived. I guess, I cant manage sending them both with single thread.

Comment: I fail to see the difference.  Isn't that just another query with different query results?

Comment: @Hans, no the customer may always create email campaign from the web Interface. The engine has to listen all the new arrivals and start immediate sending process. By the way, the engine works on a server right now and the server is just for that engine to work. mail server is also on that machine. The server is a 64 bit one.

Comment: If the server is working down a list of, say, 10000 emails from a previous request then it is unlikely that you'd want to allow somebody to break in and put their 100000 emails ahead.  Prioritizing this is up to you.

Comment: Isnt it the time to use multithread. If there are 10.000 emails in the queue and another 100.000 request just came, they have to be sent at the same time, which I did opening bunch of new threads :(